# How to set value to Firebase Realtime Database in background?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I call setValue() in Background like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let semaphore: DispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("data")
    let data: NSDictionary = [
        "test" : "test"
    ]
    ref.setValue(data, withCompletionBlock:{
        (error, reference) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            print("success")
            semaphore.signal()  
        }
    })
    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

But completion block never called. Is it impossible to upload data in background?

Comment: Got same problem. POST request to other servers works in background, but Firebase do nothing

Comment: Any updates on this @Shangri-La? I tried @DimaRostopira suggestion with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Apple allows few of the features to be called in background

1. microphone
2. location updates
3. bluetooth accessory
4. Voip

Comment: But we can get data from database in background.

Answer (score 0):

`keepSynced(true)` did the trick for me, just add to your code

```
let semaphore: DispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("data")
let data: NSDictionary = [
    "test" : "test"
]
ref.keepSynced(true)
ref.setValue(data, withCompletionBlock:{
    (error, reference) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
    } else {
        print("success")
        semaphore.signal()  
    }
})
_ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
completionHandler(.newData)
```